# jquery code is returning a value of true even though the target text is not visible on the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which I made the with google forms editor and then whose html code I copied and pasted into the goole apps script.  I modified some code in the pasted html code and added some javascript code to handle what happens after the user clicks the submit button.  When they click the submit button, I want to check to see if there are any errors in the form, if not then process the form.  The javascript validation has already been done for me. If the user leaves a field blank when they click the submit button. The browser will dynamically display the message "This is a required question" below each of the fields that are blank. Remember, this message does not appear on the webpage when they initially load the page, only when fields are blank when they click the submit button.  When they click on the submit button, I have jquery code that is supposed see if the message "This is a required question" was output onto the webpage using the following code, but it still displays the alert box with the error message "Found errors in the form, please correct them!" when no fields are blank:

```html
<script>
  if ($('div:contains("This is a required question")').length > 0) {
    alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');
  } else {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Success).withFailureHandler(failed).processForm();
  }
</script>
```

I also tried this but still getting the alert box:

```html
<script>
  if ($('div:contains("This is a required question")').is(':visible')) {
    alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');
  } else {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Success).withFailureHandler(failed).processForm();
  }
</script>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Or maybe I should ask this question:

If you have a div element in your code that has innerHTML and which is not currently visible on the webpage (remember, in my html code this div element is only dynamically displayed on the webpage and is invisible until its displayed by a trigger like leaving a filed blank), then how can you determine if it is visible on the webpage?

HTML Page Code:

```html
. . .

<div class="ss-form">
  <form id="ss-form">
    <ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1291373891">
              <div class="ss-q-title">First name
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.1291373891" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1291373891" dir="auto" aria-label="First name  Please enter only text" aria-required="true" required="" pattern=".*^[a-zA-Z ]*$.*" title="Please enter only text">
            <div class="error-message" id="1315894232_errorMessage">Please enter only text</div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1625515457">
              <div class="ss-q-title">Last name
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.1625515457" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1625515457" dir="auto" aria-label="Last name  Please enter only text" aria-required="true" required="" pattern=".*^[a-zA-Z ]*$.*" title="Please enter only text">
            <div class="error-message" id="644912485_errorMessage">Please enter only text</div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1285054831">
              <div class="ss-q-title">PSU ID #
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.1285054831" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1285054831" dir="auto" aria-label="PSU ID #  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <div class="error-message" id="511976623_errorMessage"></div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_178454387">
              <div class="ss-q-title">Street address
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.178454387" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_178454387" dir="auto" aria-label="Street address  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <div class="error-message" id="610906300_errorMessage"></div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_11303954">
              <div class="ss-q-title">City
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.11303954" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_11303954" dir="auto" aria-label="City  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <div class="error-message" id="1949506785_errorMessage"></div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_155894393">
              <div class="ss-q-title">State
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.155894393" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_155894393" dir="auto" aria-label="State  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <div class="error-message" id="1985746458_errorMessage"></div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_231948907">
              <div class="ss-q-title">Zipcode
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.231948907" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_231948907" dir="auto" aria-label="Zipcode  Please enter a valid zipcode" aria-required="true" required="" pattern=".*^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$.*" title="Please enter a valid zipcode">
            <div class="error-message" id="272269539_errorMessage">Please enter a valid zipcode</div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_548544274">
              <div class="ss-q-title">Phone number
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr">***-***-****</div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.548544274" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_548544274" dir="auto" aria-label="Phone number ***-***-**** Please enter phone number in the correct format" aria-required="true" required="" pattern=".*^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$.*"
            title="Please enter phone number in the correct format">
            <div class="error-message" id="62405036_errorMessage">Please enter phone number in the correct format</div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_568775183">
              <div class="ss-q-title">PSU email
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"><a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.568775183" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_568775183" dir="auto" aria-label="PSU email example@example.com Please enter email address in the correct format" aria-required="true" required="" pattern=".*^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$.*"
            title="Please enter email address in the correct format">
            <div class="error-message" id="654653843_errorMessage">Please enter email address in the correct format</div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
        <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
          <div class="ss-form-entry">
            <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1508259247">
              <div class="ss-q-title">Semester and year applying for?
                <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
              </div>
              <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr">for example: Spring 2015</div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="entry.1508259247" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1508259247" dir="auto" aria-label="Semester and year applying for? for example: Spring 2015 " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
            <div class="error-message" id="962184537_errorMessage"></div>
            <div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      . . .
    </ol>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  function dopost() {

    if ($('div:contains("This is a required question")').length > 0) {
      alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');
    } else {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Success).withFailureHandler(failed).processForm();

    }


  }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you hiding the validation divs?

Comment: @dustmouse I don't know how that is being done because I did not write the html code for this form. The form's html code was generated by Google's form creator/editor. By the way, there is more to the html code i posted above. I could not post the entire 700 lines of code here.

Comment: May be you should use the `div` class `required-message` to target it.

Comment: @LShetty how do you do that?

Comment: Is this what you wanted? => [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2vmk9sgv/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2vmk9sgv/)

Comment: @LShetty I'm not sure.  Your code is checking to see if those div elements with the `required-message` class are visible in the **html code only** and not on the webpage, right? I need a way to have jquery detect if the message/text "This is a required question" is currently displayed on the webpage (remember this message is displayed dynamically). Also, your code output is saying it found 10 instances of divs with a `required-message` class that is visible. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Because there are 10 instances that are visible!

Comment: @LShetty I think I know what is going now. That div element with the innerHTML text "This is a required question" is being hidden from the webpage somehow and jquery is still detecting it as being visible on the webpage even though it is hidden.